# iOS String format

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following issue in swift

I have a String

```
let GET_LISTING = "Listing/GetDetails?deviceid=%@&listingid=%d";
```

the I use this line to get it formatted

```
let url = SERVER_URL + String.localizedStringWithFormat(GET_LISTING, deviceId, listingId);
```

when the number < 1000 it works fine

for example

```
Listing/GetDetails?deviceid=AB11F1D0-153E-48C3-950F-CC773BBCC683&listingid=500
```

if number > 1000 it is wrong

```
Listing/GetDetails?deviceid=AB11F1D0-153E-48C3-950F-CC773BBCC683&listingid=1,050
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Is there a `stringWithFormat` function instead of `localizedStringWithFormat`?

Comment: @rmaddy no there is no stringWithFormat function in String

Comment: Try `let url = SERVER_URL + String.localizedStringWithFormat(GET_LISTING, deviceId, String(listingId));`

Comment: There is a `String(format:, arguments:)` constructor in swift. Also, you should consider using String interpolation: `"Listing/GetDetails?deviceid=\(deviceId)&listingid=\(listingId)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the `listingId` to a `String`:

```
let GET_LISTING = "Listing/GetDetails?deviceid=%@&listingid=%@"
let url = SERVER_URL + String.localizedStringWithFormat(GET_LISTING, deviceId, String(listingId))
```

Comment: you mean let GET_LISTING = "Listing/GetDetails?deviceid=%@&listingid=%@"

Comment: Sure.  I thought `%s` would work, but `%@` certainly should.  Changed it.